# Why doesn't this work when calculating the residue?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$f(z) = \frac{z-\pi/2}{1-\sin z}$
I have to calculate the residue at $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

This is what I did:

Since $1-\sin (\pi/2)$ = 0 and $-\cos (\pi/2)$ = 0 and $\sin(\pi/2) \neq 0$, then we have a pole of order $2$ at $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
So
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,\frac{\pi}{2}) = \lim_{z\rightarrow \pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \left[\frac{(z-\pi/2)^2(z-\pi/2)}{1-\sin z}\right]\\=\lim_{z\rightarrow \pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\left[\frac{(z-\pi/2)^2}{-(\sin z - 1)/(z-\pi/2})\right]$$
The denominator is the definition of the derivative of $\sin z$ at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so it evaluates to $\cos(\pi/2)$. But this will make the expression undefined...

Comment: I get pole of order $1$

Comment: How did you determine this?

Comment: To check if the pole is of order 1, inspect the limit $\lim_{z\to \pi/2} |(z-\pi/2) f(z)|$. Is it finite or infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since\begin{align}\frac{z-\frac\pi2}{1-\sin z}&=\frac{z-\frac\pi2}{1-\sin\bigl(\frac\pi2+\bigl(z-\frac\pi2\bigr)\bigr)}\\&=\frac{z-\frac\pi2}{1-\cos\bigl(z-\frac\pi2\bigr)}\\&=\frac{z-\frac\pi2}{\frac1{2!}\bigl(z-\frac\pi2\bigr)^2-\frac1{4!}\bigl(z-\frac\pi2\bigr)^4-+\cdots}\\&=\frac1{\frac1{2!}\bigl(z-\frac\pi2\bigr)-\frac1{4!}\bigl(z-\frac\pi2\bigr)^3+\cdots},\end{align}the residue is equal to $2$.

Comment: How do you see it from here since its not in the form $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k (z-\frac{\pi}{2})^k$? because it's a reciprocal of a taylor series

Comment: @similarityinvariance1 Because it is equal to$$\frac2{z-\frac\pi2}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac1{12}\bigl(z-\frac\pi2\bigr)^2+\cdots}$$and the second factor is analytic near $\frac\pi2$.